# Is there a way to make python subprocess not terminate after running through the script once?

Tags: python, subprocess

Consider the following 2 files

`script_to_start_other_script.py`

```
import schedule
import time
import subprocess 

def run_again():
    subprocess.call(["bash", "-c", "" + "  nohup python script_to_be_started.py > /dev/null 2>&1&"])  


if __name__== "__main__":

    schedule.every(5).seconds.do(run_again)

    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)
        pass
```

`script_to_be_started.py`

```
import logging
from logging.handlers import TimedRotatingFileHandler

# Init logger
logger = logging.getLogger('test_log')
hdlr = logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler('./test_log.log', when='h', interval=10)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s : %(message)s')
hdlr.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(hdlr)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger.info('Beginning of test_log.py')

import schedule

def run_again():
    logger.info('I am being called')

if __name__== "__main__":
    schedule.every(5).seconds.do(run_again)

    while True:
        logger.info('how many time am I being called')  
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)
        pass
```

Whenever I run `script_to_start_other_script.py` , `script_to_be_started.py` will only run the entire script once

```
logger.info('how many time am I being called')
```

will only print once even though there is a while loop. Is there a way for the script to keep running?

Comment: How are you reading the output of your spawned processes?

Comment: I use the logger from `import logging`

Comment: Even after adding the missing `import`s and initializing a logger, your code produces no output. Can you edit your two scripts so that they actually run and reproduce your problem?

Comment: yeah let me give you the full script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried you first script and it continuously ran the second one. Try to just run the `script_to_be_started.py` and make sure that it runs fine. One reason that the second script ran until the log statement might be the missing import for time.

`import time`

So, after printing the log message, the second script will silently crash because of missing import.

I am assuming you only stripped down the logging stuff but the missing import for time is actually part of your code.